# Better way to replace text in globally except using SendKeys.Send

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net

I'm trying to create an IME (Input Method Editor) or something similar to that as helping to type ANSI local language font.

it needs to replace some characters when the user types anywhere in Windows. (Word, Photoshop Coreldraw etc.)

For example when user type **"r"** character and **"E"** character, IME need to replace **"rE"** with **"ú"**. I'm using a low-level key hook to capture keypress and `SendKeys.Send` to replace characters.

```
If chkStr = "rE" Then
    SendKeys.Send("{BS}") 'backspace for delete "r"
    SendKeys.Send("{BS}") 'backspace for delete "E"
    SendKeys.Send("ú") 
End If
```

It works. But some applications (i.e Adobe InDesign) have inbuilt key shortcuts such as `shift + backspace`. when user type "e" with **shift key** it combine with SendKeys.Send("{BS}"). the result is it calling the key shortcut. I hope experts in here can give me a solution for it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what if user typed r in notepad and typed E in Word doc?

Comment: what if I type rE in the browser without being in a textbox? Will it do a back?

Comment: @Steve I use process ID to identify the window.

Comment: @the_lotus user must **Enable** IME in system tray before he types local lang font

Comment: usually IME will swallow the keystroke and output text once user hit enter rather than deleting them on the fly.

Comment: Have you tried [using this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Intl/input-method-manager)?